Is the Haar Measure on a Group the Only Reasonable Way to Define Randomness?
Given a compact topological group $G$ and a closed subgroup $H$. Let $d \mu_H$ and $d \mu_G$ be the respective unique Haar measures. In general, when we say "pick a random element of $H$," what is meant is that the latter is distributed w.r.t $d \mu_H.$ Is this the only reasonable way to define randomness? Would it be reasonable/interesting for example to generate random elements of $H$ that are distributed w.r.t $d \mu_G$? And, what does it take for an element distributed w.r.t $d \mu_G$ to be also distributed w.r.t $d \mu_H$?

The Haar measure should be thought of as a "uniform distribution" on our group. This is expressed by the fact that the Haar measure is invariant with respect to translation (action by a group element). Now, it is reasonable to believe that there is only one "uniform distribution" and this is indeed the case (Haar measure is unique for compact groups). On the other hand, if you don't want to pick stuff uniformly at random, then there is no reason to consider the Haar measure.

In case one is interested in picking stuff uniformly, how satisfying would it be to allow one to pick stuff in $H$ uniformly w.r.t to $d \mu_G$ rather than $d \mu_H$. In other words, what are we losing here

Well, that depends on what you want to do. If your samples will only live in $H$ anyways and you want them to be uniformly, then you want to use $d\mu_H$. As always the distribution needs to be chosen depending on what you would like to model. If you are rolling a fair die, then the uniform distribution on ${1, 2,3,4,5,6}$ is fine, for a fair coin flip, that is not a great idea.

a.e. I am happy to answer questions here on math.stackexchange. If you happen to have a follow-up question this is a great place to ask it.

The Haar measure should be thought of as a "uniform distribution" on our group. This is expressed by the fact that the Haar measure is invariant with respect to translation (action by a group element). Now, it is reasonable to believe that there is only one "uniform distribution" and this is indeed the case (Haar measure is unique for compact groups if we normalize it (Rudin) Uniqueness of Haar measure's proof). On the other hand, if you don't want to pick stuff uniformly at random, then there is no reason to consider the Haar measure.
So it depends on what you want to do. If your samples will only live in $H$ anyways and you want them to be uniformly, then you want to use $d\mu_H$. As always the distribution needs to be chosen depending on what you would like to model.
If you are rolling a air die, then the uniform distribution on $\{1, 2,3,4,5,6\}$ is the way to go. However, if you want to model a fair coin toss, then you want the uniform distribution on $\{ 1, 2\}$ (note that I can realize both as Haar measure on $G=\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, respectively $H$ being the subgroup generated by the residue class of $3$).

Thanks! I'm interested in the general question, but let us give a specific example so the question is clearer. Say, $G=O(N)$, the group of $N \times N$ orthogonal matrices (compact) and H is any closed subgroup. Say we're interested in generating random elements of H. But, you have limited knowledge on $d \mu_H$. Now, say it is possible to generate an element of G that is distributed w.r.t $ d \mu_G $ and you could do complicated stuff to it and get an element of H that is still distributed w.r.t $ d \mu_G .$ How reasonable/interesting is this process of generating random elements of $H$?

That does not seem possible. If you force your elements to end up in $H$, then the distribution cannot be the same as $d\mu_G$ unless $G=H$ (you never hit anything in $G\setminus H$). Maybe you can include what you have in mind in your post? I am probably misunderstanding what you want to do.

For my problem, this is actually possible by the invariance property (I'm not forcing the same element to be in $H$ but rather using the invariance property to get an element of $H$). I just need to know if it would be interesting to generate "such random" elements of $H$.

@a.e I don't think it is. Same distribution means morally that the probability of hitting elements is the same. The probability of hitting stuff in $G\setminus H$ is nonzero for $d\mu_G$ (as it is an open set and we can cover $G$ by finitely many copies of $G\setminus H$ by compactness). Please include in your post what you actually mean.

Thank you. I'll look more into this. I believe for my case it should be interesting, but I just don't have the reason. My thoughts for my problem are that my group $H$ is an interesting group on its own, and generating any elements of $H$ would itself be interesting, let alone being able to generate elements that are uniformly distributed over $G$. I was hoping to find some "probabilistic significance" of this process. Could you please clarify what you want me to add to my post?

I do not really understand what you are trying to do. It would help if you could formalize the process and the question. Namely, what are you starting from, what are you exactly doing and what would you like to achieve. Maybe an example illustrates why I don't think that distribution wrt $d\mu_G$ is what you mean. Pick $G=\mathbb{S}^1$ and $H$ a finite subgroup. Then the Haar measure is the usual uniform measure on $H$. However, every point has measure zero for the Haar measure on $G$.
